# AVSpeechSynthesizer Voice not changing

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I am using `**AVSpeechSynthesizer**`, the following is the code to pass text to `**AVSpeechSynthesizer**`.

```
func speakOutText(_ textToRead:String ){
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
    }
    let speakUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance.init(string: textToRead);
    speakUtterance.voice  = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-IN")
    speakUtterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.2
    speakUtterance.rate   = 0.5
    speechSynthesizer.speak(speakUtterance)

}
```

It is speaking the text properly in a female voice.

But if I change male voice in **settings -> Siri & Search -> Siri Voice -> Gender(Male)**. Again calling `speakOutText` method, it is speaking the text in female voice only, not in a male voice.

**Can anyone please let me know the reason, why it is not changing to a male voice**?

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone please let me know the reason, why it is not changing to a male voice?

**Siri** and **AVSpeechSynthesizer** voices aren't the same ones and aren't located at the same place in the settings *(iOS 13.3)*:

- **Siri** ⟹ *Settings* → *Siri & Search* → *Language* and *Siri Voice*.
- **AVSpeechSynthesizer** ⟹ *Settings* → *Accessibility* → *Spoken Content* → *Voices*.

> But if I change male voice in settings -> Siri & Search -> Siri Voice -> Gender(Male)... it is speaking the text in female voice only, not in a male voice.

The `AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceGender` property is only a getter that can't help you to change the gender voice.
To do so, you must specify the exact voice you want to use either with the settings *(see the point above)* or programmatically if need be: beware of the current language code *(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.currentLanguageCode())* that is used in your app because it will be taken as default if you don't literally change the utterance voice.

Writing the code hereafter *(iOS 13, Swift 5.1)*:

```
let allVoices =  AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
    
var index = 0
for theVoice in allVoices {
    print("Voice[\(index)] = \(theVoice)\n")
    index += 1
}
```

...  will display all the available voices on your device:
[image]

Indicate the voice utterance in this list to get the appropriate voice gender

Conclusion: changing the AVSpeechSynthesizer voice has nothing to do with Siri even it can be done in the settings that will be adapted to the current language code unless everything is specified programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
private let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

var Rate: Float = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
var USMaleVoice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

func Say(_ phrase: String)
{
    let Utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: phrase)

    Utterance.rate = Rate

    Utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

    synthesizer.speak(Utterance)
}
 //Print all voices ↓  
func GetVoices()
   {
    AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().forEach({ print($0)})
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use This

```
  AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceGender.male
```

if you have any doubts follow the [appleLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesisvoice#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVSpeechSynthesisVoice/voiceWithLanguage:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Based on the settings, i have to change. I don't want to give static value as male or female. Is any possibilites are there?

Comment: did you use? . AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceGender.male

Comment: In which property i have to use this?

Comment: Where i have to declare, AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceGender.male? Can you please le me know?